# Passing checkbox-bool value from HTML to mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, mongoose

How do I pass checkbox's value from HTML to mongoose? `Checked = true`, `unchecked = false`

```
const newSomething = {
   isTrue: req.body.isTrue //dosn't work with my HTML
 }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="isTrue">
```

Comment: add a fiddle or post code on how you are submitting form and ajax method .

Comment: @dev9 I believe handlebars helps me to submitting this form, by a simple `<button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>`. Forgot to mention about handlebar, sorry.